# Extracting foreground from video stream

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, background-subtraction

I am working on a video processing project which takes camera feed as input and have got a static background. I dont need any sort of dynamic background generation as that of BackgroundSubtractorMOG in opencv. I am trying to bound foreground object inside bounding boxes. So for that this is what I did

```
cv::absdiff(back_frame,matProcessed,temp);         //back_frame is the background matProcessed is the frame from CAMERA in grayscale
cv::threshold(temp,temp,20,255,THRESH_BINARY);

cv::findContours(temp,contours,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
std::vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
std::vector< std::vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );

int j=0;
for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{
           if(contourArea(contours[i])>100)
           {
               approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 10, true );
               boundRect[j] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
               j++;
           }


 }
 cv::rect r;
   for (int i = 0; i < boundRect.size(); i++)
    {
        r = boundRect[i];

        cv::rectangle(
            frame,
            cv::Point(r.x, r.y),
            cv::Point(r.x + r.width, r.y + r.height),
            CV_RGB(0,255,0)
        );
    }
```

But the problem is I am not getting the foreground correctly. Is there anyway I can improve the foreground generation and always bound the foreground object using some rectangular bounding boxes irrespective of the background complexity and other factors??

Answer (score 0):

There are various simple and complex methods to do this. Going with a pixel-wise probabilistic approach is definitely recommended. You can also use stuff like Markov models on the appearance to refine your result. Refer to [this paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~yaser/SheikhJavedKanade_ICCV_2009.pdf), specifically the *Related Work* section and the last bit where they refine the foreground objects.